# PHP Variable definition/declaration with alternative values using "||" "OR"

Tags: javascript, php, declaration

In javascript we can do something like:

```
var x =  y || z;
```

How do you do the same in `PHP`?

I want something like:

```
$x = $y || $z
```

is it possible?

Thanx!

Comment: we have to assume you know *exactly* what the JS code does, but that isn't necessary true. So.. first of all: what do you want to do?

Comment: `?:` - no really, that's the answer. I'm sure this has been asked many times before too.

Comment: Read [this](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#112190). It's amazing what you can find in the manual if you bother to read it.

Comment: WHY too many Down Votes Men?... Please have merci on my Privilege I Really Beg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `$x` to be a boolean indicating the truthiness of `$y || $z` (i.e. if either `$y` or `$z` is truthy. Then what you posted: `$x = $y || $z` will work.

If you want $x to have the same value as the first non false variable you could do a ternary:

```
$x = $y ? $y : $z;
```

Comment: Sure but how do i get the typeof and make sure that no error occurs if it is undefined? i.e: in Javascript:  var x = typeof(y)!== "undefined" ? y :z; How Do you do that in PHP??

Comment: @UniversalGrasp `empty` or `isset` can both be used to check if a variable hasn't been defined. See [empty](http://uk3.php.net/empty) and [isset](http://uk3.php.net/isset).

Comment: You are the Man!... Thax a Trillion!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but it won't have the same results as in Javascript.

In Javascript, `y || z` returns the value `y` if it's truthy, otherwise it returns `z`. This is useful in variable initializations, as it allows you to assign `y`, but fall back to `z` if `y` is not set.

In PHP `||` is a boolean operator, it always returns `true` or `false`. So `$y || $z` won't return the values of the variables, it just returns whether either of them is truthy.

To get the equivalent result, you would use:

```
$x = $y ? $y : $z;
```

Since PHP 5.3, this can be abbreviated to:

```
$x = $y ?: $z;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (since 5.3):

```
$x = $y ?: $z;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is to check if the first variable is defined.
At least this is a common usecase in JS where you'd write `x = y || z`, which means nothing more than `if y is defined then x = y otherwise x = z`.
This only works because JS treats `undefined` as `false`!

In PHP you can use `isset` to test if something is set/defined:

```
$z = "test";
$x = isset($y) ? $y : $z;

echo $x; //echoes "test"
```